# Ubuntu won't boot after 12.04 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, boot

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 a few weeks ago and yesterday I upgraded it to 12.04. The upgrade manager installed all packages and then asked me to reboot my computer. Everything went well, I was able to use it without any problem.

Today I turned it on and here is my problem: **it won't boot anymore**. When it gets to the login screen it freezes.

- I tried opening a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F1 but it wouln't open.
- I rebooted and tried booting with a older kernel version but it didn't work.
- Then I booted from the recovery and tried to fix it but I couldn't.

When I was at the recovery menu I tried to activate the network option, but the **network-manager failed and the system freezed**. I think that may be the problem, but I don't know how to fix it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make a CD of Super Grub Boot disc; it will find all the OSs and allow you to choose and boot. Also try 'Try Ubuntu' from the Live CD, and install into it Grub Customizer. Launch that and you may be able to adjust the settings to get back to booting normally. Super Grub disc has got me out of trouble many times. Good luck

Comment: The GRUB is working fine. Last night it worked, but I just tried again and it didn't work

Comment: When you say 'it worked', can you give more detail about what you mean please? Do you mean Grub worked, or Ubuntu worked and allowed you to logon as normal; it was not clear from your reply, sorry.

Comment: Would it be an idea to go back and re-install 11.10 to see if that works. If you have three partitions (one of them is the 'swap file' partition) then you could install 11.10 on one and use it to investigate what is on the stubborn 12.04 partition. At least then you may be able to boot up and use your PC while you get a real fix in place. Good luck.

Comment: After using it a few more times I have realized the problem: Ubuntu only boots after booting into windows and then rebooting the computer, wich is very annoying and I still can't find the solution. When I said it worked, I meant to say it booted normally. After doing it a few more times I realized it only works after rebooting the computer from windows. GRUB is my default bootloader and it works very well for me. I'm only having problems with Ubuntu.

Comment: Update 8th May: Can you tell me which way round you did the installs: Windows, then Ubuntu, or vice versa??

Comment: Windows, then Ubuntu