# Won't boot after 12.04 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, boot-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu won't boot after 12.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132182/ubuntu-wont-boot-after-12-04-upgrade)

I am new to Ubuntu and I recently upgraded to 12.04. Now when I try to start Ubuntu nothing happens. I get a blank screen, not even a cursor. I am running a dual-boot with Windows 7 which is still working fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably some error during the upgrade or with the grub.
Upgrades are very buggy sometimes, download a fresh 12.04 Live CD and reinstall it.
Before reinstalling you can backup your files using the Live CD and a pendrive or something.